# how to start a browser with yahoo search query in android

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to start a Browser with a yahoo search query. For example user can select a certain word or phrase and click a button and the activity will start the browser with the yahoo search query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way is with intents, like so:

```
String query = "my search terms";
String url = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + query;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Android will automatically attempt to open this in the application associated with URLs which, by default, should be their default web browser.

Comment: thanks, it works fine.
but what if i want to use image search, can i change URL only or other changes will happen!?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the search keyword to Yahoo search api url and accessing it via uri onClick new button in your activity.